# Not receiving notifications from Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase-notifications

I developed an app that receives push notifications with Firebase. If I launch the application from Xcode directly on a smartphone, the notifications arrive correctly. If instead, I send the application on the Apple store and then download, the notifications do not reach me. Most likely I do not correctly configure the file to send. I would like some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1- You must create distribution push notification certificate

2- Download it and click to import in keychain

3- Export the .p12 file from it and upload to app configuration in firebase

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem.
Firebase for development and production environment is different. You are using development "Provisioning Profile" now.

Check this steps to create Production "Provisioning Profile":
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

It may take 20 min for first time. Pls be patient. Now GO!